# PHP preg_split, expression i curly brackets and saving the delimiters

Tags: php, regex, delimiter, preg-split

I've been struggling with this for like half a day already and I can't seem to find the answer. Please do help a noob. :)

I've got a string which consists of few sentences which are in curly brackets. It looks something like this:

{Super duper extra text.} {Awesome another text!} {And here we go again...}

Now I want to split it.

I figured out I could search for patterns like .} {, etc. So I did it like this:

```
$key = preg_split('/[!?.]{1,3}\} \{/',$key);
```

But this way I lost the delimiter, I lost all those . ! ? etc. at the end of the sentence.

I tried to do it like that:

```
$key = preg_split('/([!?.]{1,3}\} \{)/',$key, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$sentences = array();

for ($i=0, $n=count($key)-1; $i<$n; $i+=2) {
$sentences[] = $key[$i].$key[$i+1]."<br><br>";
}
```

But this code never loads, so I gather something's wrong with it. But what?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to split this, just call `preg_match()` on it instead. The matched groups will result in an array.  The expression grouped inside `()`, `[^}]+` matches all characters up to, but not including, the next `}`.  The output values you want will be inside the `$matches[1]` subarray.

```
$input = "{Super duper extra text.} {Awesome another text!} {And here we go again...}";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\{([^}]+)\}/', $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {Super duper extra text.}
            [1] => {Awesome another text!}
            [2] => {And here we go again...}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Super duper extra text.
            [1] => Awesome another text!
            [2] => And here we go again...
        )

)
```

Comment: This works very well in my situation where I have a string that contains several JSON substrings concatenated together.  For example:  `'{"id":"Q3","name":"Question 3"} {"id":"Q4","name":"Question 4"}'`.  The only caveat is that if there is a closing curly bracket within one of the substrings, the regex will stop on it.

Comment: @MikeFinch That complicates things. If yours are concatenated but always adjacent `{}{}`, you could `preg_split('/\}\{/', $str)` to split up the string at the `}{` junction, but you would then need to restore the closing `}` or opening `{` which `preg_split()` would remove.  If at all possible, try to make your data source output a proper JSON array of objects to begin with `[{...},{...},{...}]`

Comment: It is indeed more complicated than it needs to be.  One additional detail I did not mention before is that the data source adds a `'; | '` delimiter between the valid JSON substrings.  Alas, I am stuck with the data source doing what it does.  I had arrived at the same idea you suggested of using `preg_split()`, with a pattern of `"/\};[^{]*\{/"`.  Then, I have to re-add the missing curly brackets.

Comment: This turned out to be exactly what I needed.  The first array was used to replace template tokens with data.  The second array was used in a switch/case block to determine which tokens were being 'requested' for replacement by the template.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you need `preg_split()` for this. From what you describe, it sounds like:

```
 $array = explode('} {', trim($string, '{}'));
```

...will do the job.

Comment: Leaving my answer up there because it explains the appropriate regex, but +1 to the simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this is working, use before middle curly brackets forward slashes.

```
$keywords = preg_split("/[\{\}]/", "{hypertext} language, programming");
print_r($keywords);
```